# css not working in ie, despite ie css sheet

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I had to play with the margins on this site to get it to work on an iphone. However, IE then go out of whack.  Created a separate IE style sheet that I now is working (wasn't recognizing the white background color but now it is). But now matter what I do with margin, clear, float, padding, etc I just can't get the bottom right #content area to align properly under its buttons. Any ideas how to force IE to behave? thanks!
http://www.womensbasketballinvitational.com/[image]

Comment: It will be helpful to provide relevant code here so that we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: In the standard style sheet I have the margin-left:360px.  So in the IE stylesheet I have: '#container {
margin-left:-360px;
 float:left;
}
'

Comment: have you tried : #access {clear:both;}

Comment: the '#access {clear:both;}' is a great idea, except that when there is more content in that stupid left sidebar, that whole area will get pushed down the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to learn how to deal with floatting elements.
this : `#access {clear:both;}` you put things back together :)

here: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: yeah, inherited mess I'm picking through...

Comment: and as said in other question, updated something like #access  {
clear:both;
}
 #container {
margin:0 35px 0 0;
float:right;
} will help too or make #access and #container float on left side :)

Comment: ha! the '#access' did end up fixing it, but only after I changed the order I had it in the IE css.  Of all the stupid nitpicking things to waste my time on (and yours)!

Answer (score 1):

Since `#container` is on the right side of the page, maybe `float: right;` instead of `left`?

So...

```
#container { float: right; margin: 0 41px 0 0; }
#content { margin-left: 0; }
```

Comment: good idea, but it broke in chrome and did nothing for IE.

Comment: the clear on #access is the first step, for the rest you have many options, but i'll keep my mind on adjacent containers #access/#container , childs will follow

Comment: @Elaine Works for me in both when I make the changes in the inspector (lines 84 and 615).

Comment: yes, I did get it to work (see comments above) but for some reason had to change the order of in the IE stylesheet. Ugh!